# Interconexão de tabelas no MySQL em programa Java

Tags: java, sql, query

Boa tarde senhores e senhoras, estou desenvolvendo um projeto para estudo com 2 tabelas e essas tabelas precisam estar conectadas em um certo valor.
No meu pacote **DAO**, tenho 2 classes **EstoqueDAO** e **EstoqueGradeDAO** e elas correspondem a uma tabela de produtos (contendo *código, descrição, marca* e *observação*) e outra com as informações específicas do produto cadastrado anteriormente (*cod_gra, cod_est, cod_bar, valor, quantidade* e *tamanho*).
Eu preciso que os valores de **código_estoque** (coluna da segunda tabela) e **código** (coluna da primeira tabela) assumam o mesmo valor.

meu método:

```
public List<EstoqueGrade> read() {
        Connection con = ConnectionFactory.abrirConexao();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        List<EstoqueGrade> estoqueGrade = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM estoque_grade");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                EstoqueGrade eg = new EstoqueGrade();
                eg.setCod_gra(rs.getString("cod_gra"));
                eg.setCod_est(rs.getString("cod_est"));
                eg.setCod_bar(rs.getString("cod_bar"));
                eg.setTamanho(rs.getString("tamanho"));
                eg.setValor(rs.getString("valor"));
                eg.setQtd(rs.getString("qtd"));
                estoqueGrade.add(eg);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao ler dados: \n" + ex);
        } finally {
            ConnectionFactory.fecharConexao(con, stmt, rs);
        }
        return estoqueGrade;
    }

    public ArrayList retornarEstoqueGrade() {
        ArrayList estoqueGrade = new ArrayList();
        Connection con = ConnectionFactory.abrirConexao();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM estoque_grade");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                        
            if (rs.next()) {
                do {
                    estoqueGrade.add(new Object[]{
                        rs.getString("cod_gra"),
                        rs.getString("cod_est"),
                        rs.getString("cod_bar"),
                        rs.getString("tamanho"),
                        rs.getString("valor"),
                        rs.getString("qtd")
                    });
                } while (rs.next());
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao mostrar dados: \n" + ex);
        }
        return estoqueGrade;
    }
```

Eu não passei o método da outra tabela, mas é a mesma coisa com as variáveis diferentes.

**Eu não posso usar chave estrangeira** para esse caso, tenho que trabalhar **apenas com manipulação de dados.**

Se precisarem de mais informações eu passo, mas acho q não será necessário.
Vale lembrar q eu só preciso resolver isso, o cadastro está funcionando para ambas (separadamente).

**PS: eu comecei a aprender Orientação a Objeto, Java e MySQL fazem menos de 2 meses, desculpem se estiver fazendo perguntas óbvias...**

Comment: Usa JPA e mais simples, JPA atualmente e a melhor solução para programadores java